# Write output stream to a string

Tags: c++

I have a stream object `std::stringstream` and I want to get whatever it currently has as a `std::string`. Is that possible? I want it for output to my graphic console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `stringstream::str()` method for that: https://cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/

Comment: Note that `stringstream::str()` returns a *copy* of the string, not a reference to it. To update or clear `stringstream`'s `string`, use `stringstream::str(string)`.